# Install Visual Studio Emulator for Android with VS 2015 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have installed VS 2015 Professional installed in my system and want to install VS Emulator for Android as I need it for Xamarin Android development but the setup doesn't seem to have an option for it(below screenshots). Can someone suggest how I can go about with this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT..apologies for the late reply..thanks for the solution..it worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio Emulator for Android is installed with Visual Studio 2015 when you select Visual C++ for Cross Platform Development features.

If you update your VS 2015 to Update 3, you can also see the option `Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android`:

[image]

The emulator can be launched from within Visual Studio 2015 from

- Apache Cordova projects
- C++ Native Activity (Android) projects
- Xamarin Android projects

For Android development, you also need to install the Android SDK. And it is also suggested to create your own emulator with google service, for the emulator installed with VS, Hyper-V should be enabled, and for self-created emulator with Google service, Hyper-V should be disabled. Please refer to [Windows Installation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/) and [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/) to configure your environment for Xamarin Android development.